# Play framework many controllers (and session management)

Tags: playframework

For pure code organization purposes, I consider creating many controllers in my application. I found no special overhead created by a controller object. On a quick inspection of play's source, it does not seem to spawn any especially thick objects that would incur a lot of memory consumption per each controller.

However I wonder whether sessions seamlessly cross across controllers, or are they bound in some way to the boundaries of a controller. I also consider using [secure social](https://github.com/jaliss/securesocial) in case it matters.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no reason to think that sessions would not work seamlessly across different controllers. Play is designed to be as stateless as possible, so controllers shouldn't be keeping any sort of state that might make sessions behave differently.

For example, there is really no difference between:

```
object Users extends Controller {
    def read(id: Long) = Action { ??? }

    def create() = Action { ??? }
}
```

and

```
object ReadUsers extends Controller {
    def read(id: Long) = Action { ??? }
}

object CreateUsers extends Controller {
    def create() = Action { ??? }
}
```

Obviously, this isn't the ideal organizational structure we're looking for, but it conveys my point. Controllers should be organized in a manner that you think is best for your code. The *only* time session data might be treated differently is if your controller object mixes in different traits, or uses different `Action` types. I'm not very familiar with SecureSocial, but the choice of library shouldn't really be relevant.

Unless you are storing data in vars within a controller (or something similar), you should be okay.

Comment: Thanks, I am just unsure what you mean about mixing different `Action` types and different traits. There can be one controller that uses Action, one that uses DBAction, one that uses Action.async, and each controller, I assume, can host methods of all these types. What kind of "mixing" would change session handling actually?

Comment: Not very much at all, really. For example, if `DBAction` relies on some sort of property in the `Controller`, but that property is overridden by something. In the context of something I'm familiar with. In play2-auth for example, there is a `StackAction` which has behavior that relies on an `AuthConfig` trait being mixed in, and it will cause different behavior between different `AuthConfig` implementations. So really, it would be rare to use different ones. Another example would be some sort of action that mutates the session data for whatever reason (also extremely rare).

Comment: Thanks for the answer and demystifying about controllers in context!